# malloc and free when using reassign pointer

Tags: c

Please, correct me if I'm wrong. In pseudo code bellow I create space for `j`. Of couse at the end I need to free space. But if `j` was reaasigned to another variable it is not good to free variables `anotherJob` spoace and I will have memory leak of `j` anyway, because code is freeing `anotherJob`. I'm right?

```
j=malloc(sizeof(struct jobDetails));
...
j=anotherJob;
...
free(j);
```

Comment: Very bad. `free` expects the pointer you allocated, not some other, unrelated variable or pointer. If `anotherJob` was obtained through `malloc` then it, of course, will be freed by `free(j)` and whatever memory `j` used to point to is now a memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Unless you've saved the original value of `j` away somewhere else, it will get leaked. You don't likely want to free `anotherJob` here since you don't know where it came from or if it's going to be free'd somewhere else.